Wordpress Multisite migration 404 errors for other network sites
Having some problems with manually migrating over one of our comapny Wordpress Multisites from one AWS instance to another and getting 404 errors on all the other network sites other than the primary one.
The main reason for this was we needed to update the PHP version and with AWS the only way to do it was to create a new instance and migrate the site over.
Migrated over the Multisite along with the original DB and can get the main domain to load correctly, when when I go to another network site (E.g. example.com/au and even example.com/au/wp-admin) I receive a 404 and all the resources are showing as 404 as well.
Trying to migrate manually without a plugin as this site is non-transactional, if a plugin is the only solution left then I will have to go down that route.
What I have tried and done are as follows:

Created a new AWS instance
Copied over entire DB and wordpress content from original instance and imported it onto new instance
Set correct file and folder permissions for all Wordpress directories
Updated the following tables that contain the old URL to the new IP for now while I work locally and import that:

wp_blogs

wp_options

wp_site

wp_sitemeta

wp#_options - For each site




From this point the site loads and works fine but when you go to one of the network sites like example.com/au I just get 404 for pages and assets. Also when accessing example.com/au/wp-admin I get a ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS error.
Other things I have checked are enabled and working are:

Ensured correct Multisite wp-config.php and .htaccess settings are present

Checked that mod_rewrite is enabled on Apache server

Disabled all plugins to see if it was a plugin issue

Tried disabling the define('MULTISITE', true); but I just receive DB errors because the wp_1... doesn't exist

Edited the /opt/bitnami/apache/conf/httpd.conf file and changed the AllowOverride None to AllowOverride All


Running out of things to try, anyone have an ideas what might be causing this and something I have missed.
This is what I am seeing in the console for the 404 issues:
Console Errors
